# select query to fetch data exactly before 3 days with timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have db tables having created timestamp column. I want to fetch all records from postgress db which were created exactly 3 days before the current timestamp.But another constraint here is another column named **status**. there could be multiple statuses and created timestamp as the PK is timestamp,status and id. I want to fetch only those ids which was last inserted exactly 3 days before current timestamp. 
For example:

```
-----id------------timestamp--------------------------status------------col3------
.....111...............2017-10-05 10:42:23..............A..........
.....111...............2017-10-05 12:42:23..............X..........
.....111...............2017-10-05 18:42:23..............X..........   
.....222...............2017-10-05 11:42:23..............A..........
.....222...............2017-10-05 13:42:23..............X..........

.....222...............2017-10-07 18:42:23..............X..........
```

id 111 is what I want to fetch because the last record was inserted exactly 3 days before current timestamp but 222 is not the one I want it to be selected as the last entry was inserted just one day before current time stamp though the first record of 222 was inserted 3 days before.
Sorry I am not able to draw proper table here

Comment: You don't clarify what "exactly 3 days before" means.  I that to the nearest microsecond?

Comment: If current timestamp is 2017-10-08 19:42:23 then 3 days before means 2017-10-05 19:42:23

Answer (score 4):

Just use `interval` arithmetic:

```
where created_timestamp < current_timestamp - interval '3 day'
```

For the revised question, it would seem to be something like this:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(timestamp) >= date_trunc('day', current_timestamp - interval '2 day') and
       max(timestamp) < date_trunc('day', current_timestamp - interval '1 day');
```

This is a guess that "exactly 3 days before" means that two midnights have passed since then.  The logic can easily be adjusted for other definitions.

Answer (score 0):

if you usuing t-sql you can use the following predicate in WHERE phase.

> DATEDIFF ( day , column , sysdate )  <= 3